# Using Object From Parent Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple control panel controller that is responsible for extending the backend controller as well as building the control panel dashboard for the logged in user. There are two possible dashboards to load depending on the logged in user's role. If the user has a role of 4 then it loads the admin dashboard if it is anything else then it loads the regular user dashboard. If you notice below it requests a property from the `$user_data` object called role_id. This object is set in the backend controller. I did this because this object is used across most of my controllers.

When I load the control panel controller I receive an undefined variable `$user_data` as well as trying to get property of non object. Can I not set the variable inside of the backend controller and use it in the control panel as I am doing.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Control_panel extends Backend_Controller
{

    /**
     * Control_panel::__construct()
     * 
     * Load the parent construct and any additional models, helper, libraries available. 
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Control_panel::index()
     * 
     * Loads the dashboard that pertains to user's role
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->template
            ->title('Control Panel');

        if ($user_data->role_id == 4)
        {
            $this->template
                ->build('admin_dashboard_view');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->template
                ->build('user_dashboard_view');
        }

    }
}
```

Backend Controller

```
$user_data = $this->user->get_by('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$character_data = $this->character->get_many_by('owned_by', $this->session->userdata
        ('user_id'));
$user_data->characters = $character_data;

$this->template
        ->set_theme('smashing')
        ->set_layout('control_panel_view')
        ->set_partial('header', 'partials/header')
        ->set_partial('sidebar','partials/sidebar')
        ->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer')
        ->set('user_data', $user_data);
```

Comment: As your `Child` class is extending your `Parent` class, every `properties` and `methods` that are either `public` or `protected` in the `Parent` class will be seen by the `Child` class. Use `$this->user_data->role_id` instead.

Comment: I did so in the control panel controller and now I am getting Undefined property: Control_panel::$user_data

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($user_data)` to see what your working with?

Comment: also, potentially note worthy mention.. why would you keep the role in the session?

Comment: other concept.. what happens when the user wants to see the none "admin" version of the dashboard? they are automatically going to go to it everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess I am going to assume `$user_data` is not a class level variable, and that it is contained within the `function(){}` itself. Which if this is the case then after that function has complete that concept of garbage collection kills that variable, as it only pertains to the function as far as the interpater is concerned.

What you need is in your backend controller to do something like

```
class BackendController extends Whatever {
   private $_user_data = null;

   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
   }

   public function myBackend()
   {
      $this->_user_data = $this->user->get_by('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
      $character_data = $this->character->get_many_by('owned_by', $this->session->userdata
        ('user_id'));
      $user_data->characters = $character_data;

      $this->template
        ->set_theme('smashing')
        ->set_layout('control_panel_view')
        ->set_partial('header', 'partials/header')
        ->set_partial('sidebar','partials/sidebar')
        ->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer')
        ->set('user_data', $user_data);
   }

}
```

then in your front end controller

```
/**
     * Control_panel::__construct()
     * 
     * Load the parent construct and any additional models, helper, libraries available. 
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Control_panel::index()
     * 
     * Loads the dashboard that pertains to user's role
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_data = $this->_user_data;
        $this->template
            ->title('Control Panel');

        if ($user_data->role_id == 4)
        {
            $this->template
                ->build('admin_dashboard_view');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->template
                ->build('user_dashboard_view');
        }

    }
}
```